# How to interpret GDB backtrace of an OCaml program?

Tags: gdb, ocaml

I'm trying to read the backtrace of my OCaml program inside GDB. The output looks like the following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100535ac6 in .L207 ()
#1  0x0000000100535acb in .L207 ()
#2  0x0000000100535acb in .L207 ()
...
```

How can I interpret this kind of output?

EDIT:

- I've enabled debug info by using `./configure --enable-debug` (I'm using oasis).
- I'm using GDB 7.9.1 on OS X 10.10
- I'm using OCaml 4.02.2

EDIT 2: the output seems to be correct with the Linux version of GDB. Does anyone know why there is such a difference between the OS X and Linux versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what C compiler and assembler is used. Mac OS probably uses `clang` and it may not generate full debug info for `gdb`. In that case using `lldb` may be more fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

Did you compile with -g? I typically get stuff like `#3  0x0000000000401f49 in caml_program ()`. There's also `export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`, gives stacktraces when your program crashes.

(You might want to post a code snippet and the compile commands.)

You may also find http://www.ocamlpro.com/blog/2012/08/20/ocamlpro-and-4.00.0.html and http://oud.ocaml.org/2012/slides/oud2012-paper5-slides.pdf handy.

Comment: Thanks for replying :). Yes I did generate the debug info. I've already seen the slides, that's in fact what led me to post this SO question. I know for OCAMLRUNPARAM but here I really want to know more about how to debug OCaml code with GDB.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what else to say without seeing the code. Guess you could look at `grep ocamlopt _build/_log`, it should show the ocamlopt invocations (`grep ocamlc` resp.), which should have `-g`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using `ocamldebug` instead, or do you **have** to debug on the machine end?

If you want to understand what your code is doing on the CPU/Register/Assembly/Bitfiddling-witchcraft end then it might be more informative to read Jane Street's blog post [writing performance sensitive ocaml code](https://janestreet.github.io/ocaml-perf-notes.html).